# Is a Raspberry Pi processor powerful enough for a mobile chatbot?

Tags: mobile-robot, raspberry-pi, artificial-intelligence

In general, is a Raspberry Pi processor powerful enough for a mobile chatbot? I want to make a small mobile robot that is like a chatbot. Is a Raspberry Pi processor powerful enough for any type of AI robotics?
As far as a mobile robot, I want to make a wheeled robot about one foot in every dimension. The chatbot abilities will be from ProgramPY-SH, a new chatbot program that uses Xaiml databases. The chatbot works by looking through a database for a match of the user's input (vocal or text-based). It then acts according to the instructions given by the XML-like database.

Comment: AI algorithms, depending on their complexity, may require anything from a tiny MCU (check the many table top mobile robots) to a full-blown cluster (e.g. [Watson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson_(computer))). Can you be more specific on what you intend to do?

Comment: The chatbot program currently works well on laptops. The chatbot is similar to Alicebot. Specifically, I will be using Neobot or Novabot - both are ProgramPY-SH.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this type of software, but my feeling is that it should run fine on the Raspberry Pi. Despite its price the RP is rather powerful. For example, Quake 3 has been shown to run on it (doesn't Q3 include some kind of chatterbot as well? :))

Comment: If Raspberry Pi supports Quake 3, then I know that it can support my software. Set that comment as an answer so that I can mark it as the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite its price, the Raspberry Pi is a rather powerful platform that can run most Linux desktop applications but the most CPU/memory hungry. For example, Quake 3 has been shown to [run in 1080p](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e_mDuJuvZjI) on it.